# Horizontally align thumbnails

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Based on this sample code snippet from the Bootstrap [website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) I have built the following code to show two thumbnails horizontally aligned:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Filter mode</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Filter mode</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, instead of aligning them horizontally, they are stacked vertically, like so:

[image]

How can I have the thumbnails horizontally aligned as shown in the code sample [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails)?

Comment: I can't see any css file.

Comment: Me again. URL to your website doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `col-sm-6, col-md-3, col-lg-3` classes. Try to remove `<div class="col-sm-6, col-md-3, col-lg-3">`. It should work.

POST EDIT: I forgot about `.thumbnail: { display:inline; ...}`

Comment: Now the two thumbnails appear to be positioned as you want. What did you use?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add this in your CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I added your snippet to my WordPress CSS file, but the issue persists.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: You have to include the CSS. There probably is something interfering with the float variable.

Comment: The insert that is powering the `<div class="thumbnail">`. As for the website, I get error 404.

Comment: Any "style.css" in your theme folder? If yes, we want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use inline-block for the thumbnail display property, this will avoid potential clearing issues in your document flow when using floats:

```
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The example used in twitter bootstrap is using columns, so placing more than one thumb into one column will cause them to stack. Try adding into different columns to get the same effect as the example like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Filter mode</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>Filter mode</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Button</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Doing this you don't need to use any custom styles, it is intended bootstrap behaviour.

Comment: A few things you should check is **1)** Has the parent element got space to have them next to each other **2)** do the thumbnails have a set width (not width 100% say) and **3)** check that the styles are actually being applied to the thumbnail elements, it may be that you need to use a better defined selector. _you can check using any browser dev tool, like chromes inspector._

Comment: @AlexR By the way, checking the bootstrap example, the thumbnails are in separate `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3></div>` div's and the thumbnails have a max-width of 100%. This means putting more than one thumbnail into that div they will stack on top of each other. Try putting the thumbnails into separate column div's. Will edit my answer to show code

Comment: I have updated my code with your sample. The thumbnails are now positioned horizontally. However, when reducing the width of the browser screen, something strange happens: The sidebar overlays the full width. This does not happen on the other pages of my website. Do I have to change something else?

Comment: @AlexR This is because you have a responsive grid layout. At a certain `media query` break point (`min-width: 992px` in your case) the container width(containing both cols) is reduced. The thumbnails are in a `class="col-lg-9"` div and your side bar is in a `class="col-lg-3"` div. This is known as a 12 column layout. As the width of the screen becomes smaller, the minimum widths set on the two div's mean they can no longer fit next to each other, so as they are next to each other the second one goes under the first where there is space. Im guessing you are trying to create a responsive layout?

Comment: Also I checked and assuming you mean the http://worldcap.org/ site and the grey side bar, this behaviour does happen on other pages of your site (http://worldcap.org/features/) for example. Which you could expect, as they will all most likely have the same media query break points and styles.

Answer (score 1):

```
.row{text-align: center;}
.thumbnail{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: This helped in combination with @Dragos Sandu`s answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to **float** the `<div>`'s like so [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQLtH/). Using `float: left;`, `clear: none;`, `position: relative;`.